# iOS prevent files from being backed up to iCloud

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

in my app i have to store core data database. And i have some groups and folders with default data (audiofiles, maptiles, etc) in the xcode project navigator.

I found a lot about preventing files from being backed up like:
What i have done:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"%@", storeURL.path);

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    //NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES};
    /*NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];*/

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:storeURL];

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

preventing method:

```
    - (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

**(The minimum target iOS version is 7.0)**

Is this enough? How can i check if the app now prevent backing up the core data database?

Before i added the `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL` method i checked the apps storage and found nothing under documents and data. I only found 3.1 MB under backups -> my iphone

```
- Install and launch your app
- Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage 
- If necessary, tap "Show all apps" 
- Check your app's storage
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it right.
Following the Apple [Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) you should mark with the "do not back up" attribute.

For `NSURL` objects, add the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For `CFURLRef` objects, use the corresponding `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute.

To know which folder is more appropriated to store you Core Data database you can check the [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/).